# Difference of two months expenses category wise in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the difference of expenses of previous and current month in sql.

I have a table like this

```
Date       Amount Category
2/18/2015  100    Salary 
2/12/2015  150    Rent
2/21/2015  200    Allowances
1/4/2015   200    Salary
1/17/2015  50     Rent
1/20/2015  100    Allowances
```

Now I want a result like this

```
Category    CurrentMonthAmount PreviousMonthAmount Difference

Salary      100                200                 100
Rent        150                50                  100
Allowances  200                100                 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `conditional Aggregate`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Category,
                Max(CASE WHEN Month([date]) = Month(Getdate()) and year([date]) =year(getdate()) THEN amount END) CurrentMonthAmount,
                Max(CASE WHEN Month([date]) = Month(Getdate()) - 1 and year([date]) =year(getdate()) THEN amount END) PreviousMonthAmount
         FROM   Yourtable
         GROUP  BY Category)
SELECT Category,
       CurrentMonthAmount,
       PreviousMonthAmount,
       [Difference]=Abs(CurrentMonthAmount - PreviousMonthAmount)
FROM   cte
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02bfb/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do the computations within your SQL only or via some scripts like PHP.? Furthermore, can you state if you are choosing specific records for this operation (specific rows i mean). Give some more clarification

Comment: I am trying to do computation in sql only